# Array que muestre imágenes aleatorias en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy programando el juego de la lotería mexicana (con cartas personalizadas) en **Java** y quisiera mostrar las imágenes en un array para que fueran tomadas de manera aleatoria y sin repetirse. Adjunto mi código que hasta el momento funciona, pero usando `Strings` con los nombres de las cartas y de antemano agradezco la ayuda.

**Clase carta**

```
public class Carta {
   private String cara;

public Carta( String caraCarta  )
{
cara = caraCarta;

}

public String toString()
{ 
return cara; 
}

}
```

**Clase PaqueteDeCartas** que es donde cargo la GUI con código suprimido y obviado para simplicidad

```
private Carta paquete[];
private int cartaActual;


public PaqueteDeCartas2()
{
super( "Lotería Mágica" );
String caras[] = { "Strings que tienen nombres de cartas" };

paquete = new Carta[ 44 ];
cartaActual = -1;

for ( int cuenta = 0; cuenta < paquete.length; cuenta++ ) 
paquete[ cuenta ] = new Carta( caras[ cuenta % 44 ] );

Container contenedor = getContentPane();
contenedor.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
repartirBoton = new JButton( "Corre y se va con..." );
repartirBoton.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() { 

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent eventoAccion )
{
Carta repartida = repartirCarta();
if ( repartida != null ) {
pantallaCampo.setText( repartida.toString() );
estadoEtiqueta.setText( "Carta #: " + cartaActual );
}
else {
pantallaCampo.setText( "NO HAY MAS CARTAS QUE REPARTIR" );
estadoEtiqueta.setText( "Barajee las cartas para continuar" );
}
}
} 
); 
contenedor.add( repartirBoton );
barajarBoton = new JButton( "Barajar cartas" );
barajarBoton.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() { 

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent eventoAccion )
{
pantallaCampo.setText( "BARAJANDO ..." );
barajar();
pantallaCampo.setText( "SE BARAJO EL PAQUETE" );
}
} 
); 
contenedor.add( barajarBoton );
/* Cosas de GUI*/
}

private void barajar()
{
cartaActual = -1;

for ( int primera = 0; primera < paquete.length; primera++ ) {
int segunda = ( int ) ( Math.random() * 44 );
Carta temp = paquete[ primera ];
paquete[ primera ] = paquete[ segunda ];
paquete[ segunda ] = temp;
}
repartirBoton.setEnabled( true );
}

private Carta repartirCarta()
{
if ( ++cartaActual < paquete.length )
return paquete[ cartaActual ];
else
{ 
repartirBoton.setEnabled( false );
return null;
}
}

public static void main( String args[] )
{
PaqueteDeCartas2 aplicacion = new PaqueteDeCartas2();
aplicacion.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
}
```

Comment: Y si pones tus cartas como recursos de tu jar, ya sea dentro del mismo y/o fuera en lib (diferencia con uno es leerlo desde getClass().getResourceAsStream() o con lib simplemente new File("lib/"+nombreCarta+".jpg") así ya lo muestras en la interfaz?

Comment: ¿Podrías escribirme una respuesta más amplia o poner un ejemplo, por favor? Desconozco lo de usar recursos, pues no tengo mucha experiencia en Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero necesitas crear un Panel para pintar la imagen:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel(String imagePath) {
       try {                
          image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters            
    }

}
```

Luego puedes generar dentro de tu código un array con la lista de imágenes, si prefieres puedes usar un Map para mantener una relación nombre/imagen:

```
Map <String, String> images = new HashMap<>();
images.put("Carta 1", "rutaACarta1.jpg");
images.put("Carta 2", "rutaACarta2.png");
```

Entonces puedes generar un panel por cada imagen y usar ese panel en tu interfaz en lugar de pantallaCampo

Por cierto, para hacer random la list solo necesitas la lista con los paneles, o referencias, o lo que sea, y usar `Collections.shuffle(fileList, new Random(seed));`